# How to implement Redis Cache with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: redis, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I need to implement Redis cache with my Django Rest Framework site. But
when I do load test using cache_page decorator with a class it improves the request per second but an error occurs "'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'"

Views.py

```
@cache_page(CACHE_TTL)
class ParameterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Lists all the parameters present in the system.
    Can pass filter with parent set to null to get top level
    Parameters.
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Parameter.objects.all()
    filter_fields = ('parent', 'target_type',)

    serializers = {
        'default': ParameterSerializer,
        'list': ParameterSerializer,
        'detail': ParameterSerializer,
        'update': ParameterWriteSerializer,
        'create': ParameterWriteSerializer,
        'delete': ParameterWriteSerializer,
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializers.get(
            self.action,
            self.serializers['default'])

    def get_queryset(self):
        results = Parameter.objects.all().filter(weight__gt=0).order_by(
            'order_number')
        if 'no_parent' in self.request.query_params:
            return results.filter(parent=None)
        return results
```

In my Settings.py, I have also added the below code.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
        }
    }
}
```

also i have add the below middleware accordingly

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',

    # place all other middlewares here

    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

that too doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just from top of my head you are using the `@cache_page(CACHE_TTL)` at the wrong place and in the wrong way.

According to django docs' you need the `cache_page` decorator  to be above class' method not the class itself and it need to be wrapped in `method_decorator`.

Overwrite `ParameterViewSet`'s `dispatch` like below and it should do the job.

```
@method_decorator(cache_page(CACHE_TTL))
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Docs:

- [Decorating the class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)
- [Using cache with apiview and viewsets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/)

Comment: How to implement it for the whole site, I have tried using middleware, But that doesn;t work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183204/working-of-cache-page-decorator-in-django-redis-cache

Comment: How to invalidate the cache set by `cache_page` ? I tried `cache.clear` but it is still serving the cached data